# WP7 Bing Maps 'Invalid Credentials' Error

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm trying to use a bing maps control on a windows phone 7 silverlight application and it shows this error overlaid on the map.

> Invalid Credentials, Sign up for a
>   Developer Account

I've tried using app IDs from these two sites: http://www.bing.com/developers, and https://www.bingmapsportal.com/

am I doing something wrong? is there some account setting that I'm missing? For reference, here's how I'm defining the control and interacting with it:

```
<my:Map x:Name="MyMap" CredentialsProvider="<<myAppId>>"  />
```

And in the code behind:

```
var vm = this.DataContext as ItemViewModel;
Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
Location location = new Location()
{
    Latitude = vm.Latitude,
    Longitude = vm.Longitude
};
pushpin.Location = location;

MyMap.ZoomLevel = 15;
MyMap.Center = location;
MyMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to http://bingmapsportal.com and sign in with your Windows Live ID. Once signed in, click **Create or view keys** in the menu on the left. If you haven't already, create an application by entering the name, URL, and selecting a type (Mobile). Once you've got your application created, copy the long string of characters and paste it into your XAML as the value of the `CredentialsProvider` attribute.

```
<my:Map CredentialsProvider="NOTREALVF7QTW-LZfG0p7-RhSPeGvlfx3fdtgR-Gk_SB-wfF8kCj2J7nI57wjIna" />
```

Comment: so strange, I tried the appid I got from that site and it didn't work. But ok, I tried it again and it's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After much travail, I finally discovered that this occurs (at least on desktop SL; not sure about WP7) when the Thread.CurrentUICulture is set to the invariant culture. Be sure it is set to a specific culture (consider also setting Thread.CurrentCulture) in the App.Startup event handler, e.g.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You do still need AppID set, of course.