# MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync and MapServiceToken in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, geocoding

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app that uses the `MapControl` to display maps. In the `MapControls` `Loaded` event, I set a valid Bing API key

```
void MyMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyMap.MapServiceToken = the key
    MapService.ServiceToken = the key
}
```

I know the Bing API key is valid because the watermark in the `MapControl` is not shown.

From the page with the `MapControl` I navigate to another Page where in the ViewModel I try to find a driving route:

```
var driving = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition
{
    Latitude = Latitude,
    Longitude = Longitude
}), Detail.GeneralInfo.GpsCoordinates.Position, MapRouteOptimization.Time);
```

The problem is that `driving.Status` is always `InvaldiCredentials`.

Is there something that I am missing?

The documentation says

```
Note that you have to provide the authentication token in two separate properties in an app that uses both Map services and the Map control.
```

and I did this.

The Bing API key I use is generated for Basic / Public Windows Phone App. I also tried to generate one for Basic / Public Windows App, no change.

Comment: Does the other page also have a map control?

Comment: No. I also tried to call `MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync` from the ViewModel for the page with the `MapControl`, same result.

Comment: Does it work if you do the whole thing from code instead of a mix of XAML and code?

Comment: No, still InvaldiCredentials when calling the code fragment from code behind of the page with the MapControl

Comment: In my experience this sort of thing can be down to the difference between live and dev environments.  Does this apply to you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/c33be937-59a5-4b30-a9e7-cb2b870f6ed9/bing-map-control-invalid-credentials-when-connecting-to-staging?forum=vemapcontroldev.  Other than that, I'm pretty much out of ideas :)

Comment: Someone here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283310/wp7-bing-maps-invalid-credentials-error) got the key again and applied it and it miraculously worked.  Could be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working app that uses this token. I only set it to a Map control in XAML, and then I can use both the Map and the MapService, apparently.

My Maps key token is 22 characters long. The only way to get it is, AFAIK

- Make an app
- Upload it to the store *but do not submit*
- You app gets associated with a store ID and you will see a map token
- THAT is the token you will need

See screenshot. Is that the procedure you followed?

[image: screenshot from dev center]

Also, make sure  xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps", not the old Bing control. Don't even know if the old control is still available in the Universal Apps btw

Comment: I had to manually edit the Package.appxmanifest file to make all the guids match and then it started to work, thanks!

Comment: That is odd. Usually the project/store menu option takes care of that. Make sure you don't re-use other apps' ids or you will run into funky problems when you submit.